# Flurry mobile analytics unreliable

Tags: android, statistics, analytics, flurry

I'm trying to monitor some events with parameters in my Android app using the Flurry mobile analytics SDK. Both apps follow the same codebase, one has managed to register some events with the parameters but misses all the ones I action myself and the other app just doesn't receive any events at all. I've checked the obvious like SDK version, Flurry app ID, net connectivity etc.

Basically I'm finding Flurry to be horribly unreliable, missing events and not registering an app at all. Their events page says stats will be updated as soon as their system receives them but realistically it takes hours for the events that do succeed.

Has anybody else had this experience?

Comment: Flurry Analytics is free. Also, for what it's worth in my experience it's been fairly reliable.

Comment: Oops you are right, I was confusing my payment to another similar service.

Answer (score 0):

The event logs should show up within 5-10 min of the session occurring on the device. For an Android app, please ensure that each startSession call is matched to an endSession call.

I work with the support team at Flurry, and if you could send all project details to support@flurry.com, we can help you in a much better way.